# Edit QuickTime movie and track headers

Tags: macos, video, quicktime

I have files captured with a GoPro camera that was not properly set up with the correct time and date, leaving me with a set of .mp4 videos that have invalid timestamps in the headers.

[Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) properly displays the headers as:

```
[..]
Create Date                     : 2012:01:03 14:09:17
Modify Date                     : 2012:01:03 14:09:17
[..]
Track Create Date               : 2012:01:03 14:09:17
Track Modify Date               : 2012:01:03 14:09:17
[..]
Media Create Date               : 2012:01:03 14:09:17
Media Modify Date               : 2012:01:03 14:09:17
```

And those correspond to the headers [in the Apple QuickTime specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/qtff/QTFFChap2/qtff2.html). However, the dates are wrong since the videos were shot in January 2013.

Unfortunately, exiftool cannot write MP4 headers, only read them, so I need a tool to be able to edit the timestamps on those headers.
I've tried several programs and Python libraries with no luck, so I was wondering if someone knows of a program or library that would allow me to edit those.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found two ways to do this, but they both have the caveat of stripping out the camera specific metadata, which to me is unacceptable, so I am still searching.  For those that don't care about this information, here are the solutions I found:

First, you can do it the janky way by changing your clock, opening the file in QT and then re-exporting it.  Why there is no direct editable field for this without having to change the host clock time is beyond me.

Second, you can use ffmpeg in a non-transcoding way as such: `ffmpeg -i infile.mov -acodec copy -vcodec copy -metadata creation_time='2004-08-06 13:00:00' -f mov outfile.mov`

Comparing the exif data using exiftool will show that the camera specific tags were not copied.  Even using `-map_metadata 0:s:0` in ffmpeg will not solve this.